# Dynamic View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, dynamic

I just need to find out several things about iOS views and layout. I have just ended application where I had to create a controller that show test. It was easy except one thing. There was two types of question A and B. A questions have 4 variants of answers, B questions don't. So I had to generate all my layout in code depends on question type. I've done it by creating method `update` where i rebuild my views.

```
- (void)update {
    for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //label initialization with frame calculation
    UILabel *questionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(PADDING,       PADDING, size.width - 4 * PADDING, 0)];
    [questionLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:questionContainerView];

    //If type A
    if ([self.question.questionType isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        for (Answer *a in self.question.answers) {
            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(PADDING, offset, size.width - 2 * PADDING, 30 + PADDING)];
            //customization
            [self.view addSubview:button];
            offset += button.frame.size.height + MARGIN_BOTTOM;
        }
        //if B type
    } else {
        UITextField *answerField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(PADDING, PADDING, view.frame.size.width - 2*PADDING, view.frame.size.height - 2 * PADDING)];
        [view addSubview:answerField];
        offset += view.frame.size.height + MARGIN_BOTTOM;
    }
    UIView *lastView = [[self.view subviews]lastObject];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, lastView.frame.origin.y + lastView.frame.size.height + 10);
}
```

And after all I think it's can't be so sophisticated. Please help to find out how should I do it properly, because I am sure my method is not optimal. Maybe create custom layout. I mean how to avoid setting frame and simply add views which take right position.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely vague and I am assuming you are against using any GUI tools? Regardless, rather than creating each view after each update why not just create both views then hide or show them depending on the question?

You can do this simply using `bringSubviewToFront` or `sendSubviewToBack` or simply setHidden. That way you can create your views and simply show or hide them without destroying them and recreating everything although something this simple can easily be done that way.

My advice? Create these subviews using a storyboard or Xib then simply hide or show the view of your choice. That way you can easily layout the views however you like without touching any code.

Now, if the questions all change constantly than this is the EXACT place you would want to use a UITableViewController as this is what it's designed for. You can create a few custom UITableViewCells for your different question scenarios then reuse them depending on the type of questions. Then you simply update your dataSource for the tableView and all of your new questions appear how you like.